# How to combine IF and TEXT in a function?

Tags: excel, function

Currently I have row A displaying the day of the week based on the date in row B.

I am using the function:

```
=TEXT(B:B, "dddd")
```

However, this defaults to displaying "Saturday" when there is no date in the cell next to it. I would like to have it display nothing at all when there is no date. I'm thinking I need to use IF for this, but don't understand how to.

This is what I have so far:

```
=IF(B:B<>"", "TEXT(B:B, "dddd")", " ")
```

but this doesn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove quotes around the TEXT function.

Comment: Ha ha, wow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ScottCraner that's the perfect answer, why not post it as the answer so  Rom can accept that? :)

Comment: @brandizzi because, myself and two others see this as a typo and as such should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with an IF statement and an ISBLANK statement. The formula below follows this sequence:
1. Evaluate the conditional: Is the cell in column B blank?
2a. If it IS BLANK, put the next parameter (e.g. a blank string "")
2b. If it IS NOT BLANK, put the third parameter (e.g. the TEXT function which formats the column.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B:B),"",TEXT(B:B, "dddd"))
```

You got very close! Don't forget the IF statement syntax:

```
=IF(logical_statement, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

Let me know if this works for you!

EDIT: Your method works a little differently and omits the ISBLANK statement. This is fine albeit less readable. The error you ran into is actually just the quotes surrounding the TEXT function. If you want a string of text to appear *as-is*, then put it in quotes. If you want the text to evaluate as a formula, *leave the quotes out*.

EDIT: A more bullet-proof formula follows, which will only display the day of the week if the cell in column M is a date of the correct format. This formula will display an empty string if it is unable to detect a date. @paulbica

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(M:M,"mm/dd/yyyy"))),"",TEXT(M:M, "dddd"))
```

Comment: be careful with `ISBLANK` as it will return false on a cell with a formula that returns a null string.  It only returns TRUE if the cell is truly blank; no formula or value.

Comment: @ScottCraner Would `LEN(B:B) = 0` be a safer alternative for a case where a formula might result in `""`? I found a Layman's explanation [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/42495-better-explanation-null-empty-nothing-solved.html), but I'm still not confident I know the _best_ solution.

Comment: To cover more cases like errors and TRUE/FALSE values I'd go with something like `=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(M:M,"mm/dd/yyyy"))),"",TEXT(M:M, "dddd"))`